# Set DataFormatString in Annotations from a Global Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

Suppose if I have an Annotation like the following

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.00#}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

It works great. But suppose I want to replace the DataFormatString in real time i.e. some times like this {0:#.00#} and sometimes {0:#.000#} based on some application settings the user chooses. Is there a way to do that?

I tried storing the format string in a global variable, but it gives me the following error.

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

If I make the global variable constant it works but then the purpose is lost. Any advice on a work around?

Basically I would like to give the users an option to set the decimal spaces universally with out having to implement the feature on a per View/Controller basis.

I know I can put the culture using NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits. But this will ignore Zeros after the decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute requires constant string, you can't change that. Also this attribute does not provide ability to provide resource name. So, I think best way to you is creating [DisplayTemplate](http://digitaltoolfactory.net/blog/2012/04/how-to-use-ui-hints-and-display-templates-in-asp-net-mvc-3/) and EditorTemplate for this property.

```
[UIHint("Bar")]
public decimal Bar { get; set; }
```

And in Bar template you can change format based on some application settings chosen by user:

```
@model decimal

@Model.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["format"].ToString())
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Good to confirm the Annotation method will not work. But I am not able to use templates because in the actual situation the user has two category of fields. Both are of type decimal but one category might need 3 decimals while the other category needs 2 places. :\ Of course I can create two templates and attach them on a case by case basis but that again makes me apply this on a per View/Controller basis which I am hoping to avoid.

Comment: Ok.. I just got what you did there. I am new to "UIHint". Let me check if this can help me and get back. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot... this very much meets my requirements. UIHint thing is pretty useful. I don't presume you can advice me on how you would handle this when type was nullable decimal i.e. decimal?. Prob is I can't use tostring() with formatting with nullable decimal.

Comment: @ManekshVeetinal yes, set just set template model as `@model Nullable<decimal>` or `decimal?`

Comment: I had done that. Actually the issue is tostring(someformat) is not available for decimal? . So normally we need to convert decimal? to decimal before applying formatting. In this case once my template is decimal? I can't change the model to decimal from with in the template... so can't apply formatting.

Comment: @ManekshVeetinal you can use `String.Format` for nullables

Comment: Might be my lack of understanding about templates itself but since String.Format need to return the value to an output variable and Model.Value is read only, how do I use it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good library called [MvcExtensions](http://nuget.org/packages/MvcExtensions), one of it's feature is fluent metadata configuration. It allows you to construct model metadata fluently instead of DataAnnotations.
Using this library, you may accomplish your task:

```
Configure(x => x.Payment)
  .Format(() => ConfigurationManager.DataFormatString)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Basically trying to avoid any extensions as much as possible. Worried about future compatibility and stuff. :)